# How to set the default gemset in RVM with Rails & Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rvm, gemfile

I need to [specify a ruby version in my Gemfile for Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions):

```
ruby '2.1.1'
```

That works as expected. However, it messes with my local terminal as well. I try to [set the default ruby version and gemset in RVM](http://rvm.io/rubies/default) with:

```
$ rvm --default use ruby-2.1.1@rails4
Using /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1 with gemset rails4
$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.1.1 (found in /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1)
   (default)
   global
=> rails4
```

Seems fine and it works as expected. However, if I open up another terminal shell I get this:

```
Last login: Fri Mar 14 16:54:23 on ttys009
RVM used your Gemfile for selecting Ruby, it is all fine - Heroku does that too,
you can ignore these warnings with 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore /Users/scott/code/Gemfile'.
To ignore the warning for all files run 'rvm rvmrc warning ignore allGemfiles'.

$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-2.1.1 (found in /Users/scott/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1)
=> (default)
   global
   rails4
```

I want it to use the `rails4` gemset always! How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only way you could do it is to add two files to your application: `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` and add `2.1.1` in the `.ruby-version` file and `rails4` in the `.ruby-gemset` file.

You can also do this on your command line with:

```
echo 2.1.1 > .ruby-version
```

and

```
echo rails4 > .ruby-gemset
```

And that will create the files for you with the version 2.1.1 and the gemset rails4

So whenever you open a new terminal, rvm will use ruby 2.1.1 and gemset rails 4

Check out more on [rvm documentation](http://rvm.io/workflow/projects)

Hope this helps